# Is there a way to retrieve a jvm object by its hash code

Tags: java

Say I have an object and obj.hashCode() returns 8973846,

Can I call a function with the hash code and get the object back?

Comment: It would be more interesting to know why would anybody want to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `hashCode()` is not unique (i.e. different objects can have the same hashCode. Even different objects of the same type can have the same `hashCode`), so it's not possible to implement such a method.

Answer (score 1):

The best you could do would be, when you create your objects, to put them into a big `HashMap<Integer,Object>` that maps hash codes to instances. That way, you'd be able to retrieve them later.

Two major problems, though:

1. Because hash codes aren't guaranteed to be unique, you'll retrieve *something* with the right hash code, but not necessarily the thing you were expecting. You'd need to code everything so that hash codes were unique with high probability (which is going to be hard when there's only 32 bits to play with).
2. Your garbage collector is going to have a huge problem here unless you also remove objects from the hash map when you've finished with them. Normally, the garbage collector cleans up any instances that don't have any references left, but in your case, *everything* will maintain a reference inside the hash map. Welcome to Memory Leak City, Arizona.

You might try a `WeakHashMap` to alleviate the second problem, though that might cause more problems: when you try to retrieve an object later, it might have disappeared...

Comment: Why type `long` if `hasCode()` uses integers? Shouldn't it be `Map<Integer,Collection<Object>>`, there could be more than one object per hash code, right? What about a WeakHashMap, couldn't that alleviate the gc problem?

Comment: Quite right about `long` vs `int`. I don't know whether it's worth storing collections... it depends on the application, and whether it's worth retrieving *all* matches rather than just *any* match. I've edited my answer along the lines you suggest, though.